# JSON.Net serializing a derived List<T> with a non primitive type for T

Tags: c#, json.net

When I use the serializer for a class `XList<RealPOCO>` the elements are not serialized.
If I serialize a `List<string>` or even a class derived from `List<string>` it works fine.

The serializer only produces `$type`, `Capacity` and `Count` properties.

Here are serializer settings that I'm using

```
JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
    {
        new IsoDateTimeConverter(),
        new StringEnumConverter()
    },
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};
```

Comment: For some reason the generic angle brackets were left out

Comment: please properly format your code!

Comment: Without seeing your `XList` and `RealPOCO` classes, this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your likely not agreeing to the DataContract or marking the DataMember(s)

Your generic class needs to look like this

```
[DataContract]
internal  class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    internal string name;

    [DataMember]
    internal int age;
}
```

Note the `[DataContract]` Attribute above the class and the `[DataMember]` attributes above each member

These attributes tell the serializer that this object is serializable and what it is allowed to serialize.

You can see more on the [MSDN Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick reply. My definition is DerivedList from generic list of poco . A derived generic list of string works just fine and a simple generic list derived of poco works. The derived generic list does not.

Comment: @user3730943 If this answers your question please make sure to upvote and checkmark it so people know for the future.

Comment: @user3730943 in the future you need to post all of your code when asking questions on Stack Overflow. It just happens that I do a lot with serialization and this is a pretty common problem. Next time you wont be so lucky

Comment: I guess this was close. Because it was also a DataContract I had to use MemberSerialization.Fields instead of MemberSerialization.OptOut. Thanks.